# Converting time 1am to 1pm in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a dateset in excel which store date in the following format

```
12:59  
1:00
```

when it's read into matlab, it's represented

```
0.5410
0.0417
```

This has caused incorrect graph plotting. I realize that the second input should be 13:00, instead of 1:00. How can I pre-process this info in matlab before plotting graph, to be exact, what is the value which represent, 13:00 to 23:59 ? How can I check it in matlab?

Comment: When you see the time, how do you know whether it is AM or PM? Depending on this you can search for a programmatical fix.

Comment: it's taken from a device which collected data from 11am to 6pm office hour, so I know it should be 1PM. datestr(0.0417) returns 1AM. How do I know value of 1PM? With that I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your import from Excel has brought it in as a [serial Date number](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html#btgyu40)

I think you need to have a look at how your importing dates from Excel. It can be problematic due to the differing ways Excel and Matlab handle dates. Have a look at this [link](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-spreadsheets.html?s_tid=doc_12b#br0xp1s)

I expect your also going to need to use the [`DateStr`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) function

For example converting the time 01:00 pm in it's 12-hour format to a 24-hour format.

```
datestr('01:00 PM','HH:MM')
```

Edit:

Or alternativley

Look at [`addtodate()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/addtodate.html).

```
addtodate(0.0417,12,'hour')
```

This should add 12 hours to your 01:00 making it 13:00.

Answer (score 1):

As you know that all afternoon work is before 6, and no morning work is done before 6, it is really easy to fix with postprocessing:

For example like this:

```
x = [0.5410 0.0417];
idx = x<=6/24; %Or use 7 for example if you want to be more safe
x(idx) = x(idx)+0.5
```

Note that if your excel file actually does contain the AM-PM information, you may prefer to go for preprocessing instead. (Just incase people work outside office hours).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you might try the following conversion, starting from time array `tim` in the range 0-1:

```
tim2  = tim*24; 
ar = zeros(1,length(tim2));
ar(diff([0 tim2])<0) = 1;
tim2 = (cumsum(ar)*12 + tim2)/24;
```

Make sure to test it especially on the times 12pm-1am and 12am-1pm